# Dynamic component loader not working properly with index

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

I have a list of components for which data is fed by asynchronous calls. I am dynamically adding these components to an anchor point based on the row location. If I don't specify the row number, components are added to the view as soon as it gets the data.But I need them to follow based on the row location, which is not happening

```
switch{
case "grid":
    this.factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(GridComponent1);
    this.ref = this.coloneanchor.createComponent(component, rowLocation);
    this.ref.instance.gridData = this.favFilterData;
    this.ref.instance.gridTitle = gadget.Name;
    this.ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

case "donut":

  this.factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(donut);
    this.ref = this.coloneanchor.createComponent(component, rowLocation);
    this.ref.instance.gridData = this.favFilterData;
    this.ref.instance.gridTitle = gadget.Name;
    this.ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: not clear, can you rephrase the question?

Comment: rephrased little. So basically, components need to be added to the anchorpoint based on the component index value. createComponent(component, rowLocation); It is working fine if I have 3 components.

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: If there are more components, the insertion of the components at their index value is not followed. They are getting inserted at random index value.

Comment: create a plunker

Comment: Is there a way to know whether all the http requests were completed?

Comment: sure, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608025/promise-all-behavior-with-rxjs-observables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145059/discussion-between-indra257-and-maximus).

Comment: sorry, cant look today, tomorrow maybe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242124/loading-dynamically-created-components-in-order/44229216#44229216